# Filter SVN revisions using a date range

Tags: svn, version-control

## Context

I would like to list SVN revisions using a date range. For that, I use the following command:

```
svn log [URL] --revision {from date}:{to date}
```

## Issue

The thing is that I get revisions for dates that are out of range.

Here is my case:

```
> svn log [URL] --revision '{2021-05-23}:{2021-05-24}'

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r150963 | user1 | 2021-05-23 15:15:05 +0200 (Sun, 23 May 2021) | 1 line

Some message
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is fine but then

```
> svn log [URL] --revision '{2021-05-24}:{2021-05-25}'

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r150963 | user1 | 2021-05-23 15:15:05 +0200 (Sun, 23 May 2021) | 1 line

Some message
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r150968 | user2 | 2021-05-24 14:37:34 +0200 (Mon, 24 May 2021) | 1 line

An other message
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

gives me again revision 150963 while it doesn't belong to the range.

## Question

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation: [SVNBook | Revision Dates](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates). There is a note "Is Subversion a Day Early?" and it explains this behavior.

Comment: This is the case when you specify a single date but here I specify a range.

Comment: @flappy the situation is exactly the same when you specify date range or only one date.